# How to surround the cells with just one pixel

Tags: css, border

I have a grid control and I'm setting a style for it. 
In the border of cells, I want one pixel around each cell, but it appears two pixel because one from the left and one from the right.

The CSS:

```
.RadGrid_MyCustomSkin .rgRow td, .RadGrid_MyCustomSkin .rgAltRow td
{
    border: 1px solid #F0D88C;
}
```

Any help !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [border-collapse](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_tab_border-collapse.asp) property.

Answer (score 1):

give to td and table like this

```
table, td
{
    border-color: #F0D88C;
    border-style: solid;
}

table
{
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a border for one side only, maybe this will point you in the right direction :)

```
.RadGrid_MyCustomSkin .rgRow td, .RadGrid_MyCustomSkin .rgAltRow td
{
    border-left/*or -right*/: 1px solid #F0D88C;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it'll not cover the first cell.